# How to apply an index to a table for groupby statement with limit in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm experimenting with indexes to improve the performance of an app I'm working on.

My index doesn't seem to work when I apply a limit to my result.

I created have a simple index on a table

```
create table InboundSource (saddress int unsigned, day date, eventname char(80), count int unsigned);
create index InboundSourceDay on InboundSource (day);
```

If I do a query agaist the table, the index makes it dramatically faster.

```
mysql> select day from InboundSource group by day desc;
...
145 rows in set (0.22 sec)
```

If I put a limit on that query, it slows to its usual speed.

```
mysql> select day from InboundSource group by day desc limit 10;
+------------+
| day        |
+------------+
| 2015-01-13 |
| 2015-01-12 |
| 2015-01-11 |
| 2015-01-10 |
| 2015-01-09 |
| 2015-01-08 |
| 2015-01-07 |
| 2015-01-06 |
| 2015-01-05 |
| 2015-01-04 |
+------------+
10 rows in set (5.98 sec)
```

But if I do a query into a *derived* table then put a limit on *that* result, it's much faster than doing the query with the limit directly.

```
mysql> select * from (select day from InboundSource use index (InboundSourceDay) group by day desc) as A limit 10;
+------------+
| day        |
+------------+
| 2015-01-13 |
| 2015-01-12 |
| 2015-01-11 |
| 2015-01-10 |
| 2015-01-09 |
| 2015-01-08 |
| 2015-01-07 |
| 2015-01-06 |
| 2015-01-05 |
| 2015-01-04 |
+------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

---

EXPLAIN for each query:

```
mysql> explain select * from (select day from InboundSource group by day desc) as A limit 10;
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | ALL   | NULL          | NULL             | NULL    | NULL |  145 |                                                           |
|  2 | DERIVED     | InboundSource | range | NULL          | InboundSourceDay | 4       | NULL |  146 | Using index for group-by; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain select day from InboundSource group by day desc limit 10;
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | InboundSource | index | NULL          | InboundSourceDay | 4       | NULL | 23893889 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select day from InboundSource group by day desc;
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | InboundSource | range | NULL          | InboundSourceDay | 4       | NULL |  146 | Using index for group-by; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: post your explain for each one.

Comment: Did you try running your 1st query again after the 2nd? What is the execution time for that ?

Comment: Repeating queries makes no difference in the time.  The explain seems to show that it's not using the index for group-by, but my SQL-fu is not strong enough to grasp why.

Comment: You are not using a temp table you are using a derived table and forcing the use of the index. This might be the case where your table statistics are out of date,

Comment: The data inserts on a daily overnight cron and the index generated a couple hours ago.  I'll correct my question re: derived table, thanks.